Exactness of p-adic integers sequence in Serre's A course in Arithmetic
This is regarding clarification of the proof given on page 12 in Serre's A course in Arithmetic. Consider the sequence
$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z}_p \xrightarrow{p^n} \mathbb{Z}_p \xrightarrow{\epsilon_n} A_n \to 0
$$
where $A_n = \mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$. The first map is multiplication by $p^n$, and the second map  $\epsilon_n$ is projection onto the $n$-th component.
In the very beginning of the page 12 we have,(proving exactness in the middle)
" It is clear that the kernel of $\epsilon_n$ contains $p^n \mathbb{Z}_p$; conversely, if $x = (x_m)$ belongs to $\textrm{ker}(\epsilon_m)$, one has $x_m \equiv  0 \pmod{p^n}$ for all $m \geq n$ which means that there exists a well-defined element $y_{m-n}$ of $A_{m-n}$  such that its image under the isomorphism $A_{m-n} \to p^n \mathbb{Z}/ p^m \mathbb{Z} \subset A_m$ satisfies $x_m = p^n y_{m-n}$. The $y_i$ define an element $y$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p = \varprojlim A_i$ and one checks immediately that $p^n y = x$, which proves the proposition."
I don't understand how there exists $y_{m-n} \in A_{m-n}$. To say that $x \in \textrm{ker}(\epsilon_m)$ (is there a typo here? Should it be $\epsilon_n$) implies $x_m$ is divisible by $p^m$. Then $y_{m-n} = 0$. Assuming that there is a typo $\epsilon_n$ instead of $\epsilon_m$ could somone explain about the existence of $y_{m-n}$, and how they group together to form an element in $\mathbb{Z}_p$?
The question in the link suggested is same as mine, but the answer there does not resolve the question fully.
Thank you.

Make a little change of notation: let $i=m-n$.
First note that we have the following commutative diagram with exact bottom row, for every $i\geq 0$:$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\{0\}@>>>\mathbb Z_p@>p^n>>\mathbb Z_p@>\varepsilon_n>>A_n@>>>\{0\}\\
&@V\varepsilon_iVV  @V\varepsilon_{n+i}VV  @|\\
\{0\}@>>>A_i@>>p^n>A_{n+i}@>>\varepsilon_{n,n+i}>A_n@>>>\{0\}
\end{CD}
Let $x\in\ker(\varepsilon_n)$.
Then $x_{n+i}\in\ker(\varepsilon_{n,n+i})$ for every $i\geq 0$.
There exists one and only one $y_i\in A_i$ such that $x_{n+i}=p^ny_i$ by exactness of bottom row.
Moreover, we have $\varepsilon_{i,j}(y_j)=y_i$ (by uniqueness of $y_i$) for every $j\geq i$.
Consequently, $(y_i:i\geq 0)\in\mathbb Z_p$.
See also here.
